# Need to transpose the vertical data to horizontal format, but few cells in Vertical format can have more than 2 or 3 sub categories in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transpose

[This is BEFORE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2qni.png) [This is AFTER Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev46w.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209296/discussion-on-question-by-amit-shah-need-to-transpose-the-vertical-data-to-horiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on the assumption that your original data is still listed in the column direction.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, k As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)

    Set rngDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vDB = rngDB

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    For j = 2 To c
        n = n + 1
        'ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
        vR(1, n) = vDB(1, j)
        vR(2, n) = vDB(2, j)
        vR(3, n) = vDB(3, j)
        vR(4, n) = vDB(4, j)
        vR(5, n) = vDB(r, j) 'added insurance
        'For i = 5 To r
        For i = 5 To r - 1
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
                vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    With toWs
        k = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        '.Range("a" & k).Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        .Range("a" & k).Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With

End Sub
```

### Sheet1

[image]

### Sheet2

[image]

Comment: This is more efficient.

Comment: @NareshBhople, Thanks.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Is Hey i was just thinking now, is it possible to transpose data similar to Sheet 1 in your screenshot for every data which has more than 1 entry ?
Example :- if column 2 in Sheet 1 has 2 "S.B.no" lets say 1234 & overflow, then in sheet 2 , it should reflect as it is below "1234".

Comment: Also , why is every 4th row transposing like that, what if i also have extra 4-5 columns after "Export Items" which has data , then this code is not running properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I owe you this for the blunder :)
Since you need dynamic range, included inputboxes to select range
titleRange = C4:D6 and dataRange = C7:D10

```
Sub test()
ThisWorkbook.Activate
On Error Resume Next

Dim wS1 As Worksheet
Dim wS2 As Worksheet
Dim titleRange, dataRange, targetCell As Range

Set wS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wS2 = Worksheets.Add
Set targetCell = wS2.Range("B2")

wS1.Activate

Set titleRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)
    If titleRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You didn't select titleRange"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Set dataRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)
    If dataRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You didn't select dataRange"
    Exit Sub
    End If

For i = 1 To titleRange.Columns.Count

    titleRange.Columns(i).Copy
    targetCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    dataRange.Columns(i).Copy
    wS2.Range("E" & targetCell.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set targetCell = wS2.Range("B" & wS2.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

Next
End Sub
```

**Image of Sheet1**

[image]

**Image of New Sheet**

[image]