# Tagged raw data to table/table format

Tags: excel, vba

I have around some thousand rows in a single excel column in the below format

```
ParentId:xxxx
ParentName:YYY
Child Id: CCC
Parent of Child:xxx
Child name:rrrr
```

I want to make them into a table

the problem is Parent and child relationship and these to be put into a table using Excel VBA

Can some one help me with the code

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) •  Please also note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: [Here is some hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60574653/9808063) for you about  how to transpose partial data in one column  in loops.